# Wordpress remove menu items from wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

I want that in wp-admin will be only `Posts`, `Pages` and Settings, it's possible to remove al remaining `Media`, `Plugins`, `Users`, `Tools` etc.

This function remove only from dashboard `remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );`

Comment: You can use this light plugin. wordpress.org/plugins/hide-admin-menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove that menus from $restricted, that you want to prevent.

```
function remove_menus () {
global $menu;
    $restricted = array(__('Dashboard'), __('Posts'), __('Media'), __('Links'), __('Pages'), __('Appearance'), __('Tools'), __('Users'), __('Settings'), __('Comments'), __('Plugins'));
    end ($menu);
    while (prev($menu)){
        $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
        if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
    }
}
```

Credit goes to [hungred](http://hungred.com/how-to/remove-wordpress-admin-menu-affecting-wordpress-core-system/) via [wprecipes](http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-remove-menus-in-wordpress-dashboard)

Answer (score 2):

Since WordPress 3.1 you can better use [remove_menu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page)

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'prefix_remove_menu_pages' );
function prefix_remove_menu_pages() {
    remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
    remove_menu_page('upload.php'); 
    remove_menu_page('tools.php');
    // Remove any item you want
  }
}
```

from the docs:

> Please be aware that remove_menu_pages would not prevent a user from accessing
>   these screens directly. Removing a menu does not replace the need to
>   filter a user's permissions as appropriate.

And for submenu items:

> To remove submenu items in the admin, use remove_submenu_page. Using
>   remove_menu_page() will not work for submenu items.

Comment: no! never change a file in your wp-admin folder.  This should be added in wp-content/themes/YOUR_ACTIVE_THEME/functions.php. (where offcourse YOUR_ACTIVE_THEME is your current active theme)

Comment: Why is this better than the accepted answer @user63457 ?

Comment: @rhand If WordPress ever changes the way global $menu is build, the accepted answer will no longer work. Using the official function is more future proof.

Comment: You can use this light plugin. wordpress.org/plugins/hide-admin-menu